# Google Chrome Frame in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, browser, google-chrome-frame

How can I use [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) in .NET's WebBrowser control? I know I have to have:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

In the beginning of the page that I'm loading, but how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean ? Do you want to host Chrome via WebBrowser in your app ? Do you want to create some special HTML ???

Comment: Google for "Google Chrome Frame" to see what I mean.

Comment: Included the link to avoid confusion.

Comment: Do you have a specific question that isn't handled in the documentation located here? http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started

Comment: and what is the exact problem ? what does not work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome Frame is an Internet Explorer *plugin*, so `WebBrowser Control` isn't supported (since the control itself doens't support plugins).

At [this official thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chrome-frame/browse_thread/thread/5473a4625ee3bd50/30c394cfa29b3103?pli=1) is being suggested an alternative approach using Chrome Frame ActiveX itself inside your application, but I never tried it.

Answer (score 8):

Hi it's true what @ErickPetru said, but there are some other options especially with the ChromiumEmbeddedFramework. There are 2 projects targeting the .net framework. I've used CefSharp before and cefglue is new. Have a look at those for embedding a chromelike browser in a .net application.

[cefglue](https://bitbucket.org/fddima/cefglue)

[CefSharp](https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp)

Comment: For those who are interested: 
cefglue is based on Chrome/13.0.782.41
CefSharp is based on Chrome/19.0.1084.9
as of 11/7/2012 at 11:44AM