# Is it possible to use Chrome Frame in the Web browser control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control, google-chrome-frame

Guys can we enable  Chrome Frame in the Web browser control available in Visual Studio.?
If it is possible how can we do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Frame in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164743/google-chrome-frame-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

Yes , you can .
you should use [WebKit .NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) and add chrome to your form.

Comment: You are asking me to include webkit browser control,but what i want is enabling chrome frame in the already existing Webbrowser control in Visual Studio

Comment: That is internet explorer control . I don't think you can enable chrome frame for it ! and there is a question : enable from where ?

Comment: chrome frame is a plug-in for IE made by google to support HTML5 content.My question is is there a possibility to enable it in the IE control of visual studio.